How to handle the deletion of records with "shared ownership"?
Consider the following scenario:
In a trading card game, a user may offer to trade their cards. The offer can be public (any user can accept, fk_receiver_id null on insert) or private (only one user can accept, fk_receiver_id set on insert). So we have the following junction table

I want to allow users to delete their accounts. I would be happy to cascade delete most things, but the trades have two users associated so I cant just delete everything. I could make fk_offerer_id nullable and use ON DELETE SET NULL, but I dont want to allow null values on insert.
Should I make fk_offerer_id nullable anyway? Is there a better solution?
The behavior I'm looking for when deleting is:

If fk_receiver_id is set, set fk_offerer_id to NULL or other value that signals "deleted user"
If fk_receiver_id is NULL (trade is pending/cancelled), delete the record

Is there a way to handle this in the db? (Ideally without triggers)

A common solution (eg one that [se] uses) is to just empty the user of identifying data and leave it in place as a "tombstone" so the user just shows up as "deleted" with no name, address etc.

Im doing something like that, but now I lose the cascade delete on the tables I do want to delete. Im guessing the solution would be a trigger, but if you know a better way please do tell.

cascade deletes are often anyway a bad idea, as are triggers. Just decide which tables you want to delete user data from and do those in a normal procedure.

I think I agree with @Charlieface
In a real world scenario (and from my personal experience) you can easily delete  when thy are single tenant but it gets messy in a multi tenant scenario.
And in my personal experience no one really delete those data. Never. Is the sad true.
Also: different policies may apply based on different county law.
Example: a crime was committed the 27th of November at 22:00pm. Police investigate and can track that Adam Smith has an account on TradingCardGame.com.
Police now want to investigate about Adam Smith and knock at your door.
- Scenario 1: Adam Smith is a Californian citizen. California requires you to retain the data for no longer than necessary. He asked you to delete his date. You still have them? You can go in deep trouble if it turns out you haven't deleted them. Police my thank you but Adam Smith might bring you to court.
- Scenario 2: Adam Smith is a French citizen. In Europe you have to keep the data for a period between 6 months and 2 years (depending by the country and by the data). You have deleted them? Now you are in trouble because police is asking you those data. And you don't have them.
And where are the data stored? In California or in Europe?
